# How to change property pane control value from component tsx file in SPFx react solution?

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepointframework

I have created a SharePoint Framework solution and created a component under that solution and I have created a control in the property pane.

Now, I need to change the value of those controls from the component tsx file.
Can anyone help me with the same?

Thanks